# Difference between operator and non-operator versions of Python set operations

Tags: python, methods, set, operators, built-in

What is the difference between using the [`intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) method or the `&` operator on python sets. I read about how in previous versions the arguments to `&` had to be a set and not just any iterable although that seems to be no longer the case.

Is there a difference in terms of semantics, constraints, performance or simply pythonic style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods can be bound to names for later use, whereas the operators can be replaced by the operations in the `operator` module for the purpose of larger abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in functionality, although using the operators is a little faster because Python special-cases access to these methods. The performance difference in most programs is not so great as to demand that the operators be used.

Comment: Could you explain what "special-cases access to these methods" means?

Comment: I believe that Python looks up the addresses of the operator methods when the object is instantiated and stores them in a table, or something like that, so it doesn't have to do regular attribute lookups on them. I'm not 100% sure of this but I seem to remember reading it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The methods like [`intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) will accept any iterable, wheras the operators will only accept set types.

The info is below the method description in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

> Note, the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(),
> difference(), and symmetric_difference(), issubset(), and issuperset()
> methods will accept any iterable as an argument. In contrast, their
> operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some timings in Python 3 done on 3.7 GHz CPU...

`intersection` is the only one that I would say has negligible difference in performance, but the other operations seem faster where the "non-operator" version is using the flexibility to allow any `iterable` as an argument (not just an explicit `set`).

It seems that explicitly creating a `set` may (obviously or not) be a performance impact, if the decision is otherwise arbitrary, to choose between converting an existing non-set `iterable` into a `set` just to use the operator version.

#### Setup

```python
import random

nums = random.choices(range(1, 10000), k=10000) #this is a list
all_nums = set(range(1, 10000))
```

#### union `|`

```python
%timeit all_nums.union(nums)
248 µs ± 4.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit all_nums | set(nums)
409 µs ± 5.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### difference `-`

```python
%timeit all_nums.difference(nums)
387 µs ± 2.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit all_nums - set(nums)
451 µs ± 1.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### intersection `&`

```python
%timeit all_nums.intersection(nums)
477 µs ± 4.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit all_nums & set(nums)
479 µs ± 2.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### symmetric_difference `^`

```python
%timeit all_nums.symmetric_difference(nums)
421 µs ± 840 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit all_nums ^ set(nums)
557 µs ± 1.98 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I should add that the performance impact shown above is due to explicitly creating the set.  If the argument is already a set, @kindall has the right answer (operator version may be faster).